# Reference to subclass object when calling function declared in superclass

Tags: php

How do I make a function always refer to it's current class object, even when called from a subclass?

The following code will echo a: a

I need to echo b: b

```
class superclass {

    private $a = 'a';

    public function getObjectVars() {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

}

class subclass extends superclass {

    private $b = 'b';

}

$obj = new subclass();

$vars = $obj->getObjectVars();
foreach ($vars as $name => $value) {

    echo $name . ': ' . $value;

}
```

Comment: if this echo's only a:a then it is a bug in PHP, do report it.

Comment: Are there other ways of doing what I'm trying to do?
I need a generic superclass function that will use get_object_vars to mess with it's subclass properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to make the vars in subclass "protected" instead of private in order for the parent methods to access them..

Comment: How do you figure? this is expected behavior.

Comment: If I activate a method on a sub class, it should recognize the variables in the subclass, even if they are private. that is basic OOP. On the other hand, if he would have done parent::getObjectVars, then u can argue it is ok

Comment: I would expect it to behave this way because if my vars are private then by definition they are only available to this class specifically, not its children, not its parents. That's the only difference between "protected" and "private". otherwise, how would you keep a variable from overwriting a parent class variable?

Comment: but,but, you called the method on the child class, so make it work on the child class, not on the parent. Where is encapsulation if I run a method on child class and get the method to work on private members of parent class, THIS IS COMPLETELY OPPOSITE  from the encapsulation paradigm